# AngularJS - How do you convert milliseconds to xHours and yMins

Tags: javascript, angularjs, date-format, date-formatting

I've a requirement where I want to convert milliseconds to xHours and yMins in AngularJS.

For ex. 3600000 should be displayed as 1h 0m.

I tried using `date:'H:m'` and `date:'HH:mm'` from the [date formats](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.filter%3adate) on Angular's website.

But those give 19:0 and 19:00 instead of 1h 0m.

Any pointers of achieving this will be helpful.

Thanks

Comment: you can write a custom filter. `date` is not for displaying time intervals.

Answer (score 31):

Let make a custom filter for this, e.g:

```
.filter('millSecondsToTimeString', function() {
  return function(millseconds) {
    var oneSecond = 1000;
    var oneMinute = oneSecond * 60;
    var oneHour = oneMinute * 60;
    var oneDay = oneHour * 24;

    var seconds = Math.floor((millseconds % oneMinute) / oneSecond);
    var minutes = Math.floor((millseconds % oneHour) / oneMinute);
    var hours = Math.floor((millseconds % oneDay) / oneHour);
    var days = Math.floor(millseconds / oneDay);

    var timeString = '';
    if (days !== 0) {
        timeString += (days !== 1) ? (days + ' days ') : (days + ' day ');
    }
    if (hours !== 0) {
        timeString += (hours !== 1) ? (hours + ' hours ') : (hours + ' hour ');
    }
    if (minutes !== 0) {
        timeString += (minutes !== 1) ? (minutes + ' minutes ') : (minutes + ' minute ');
    }
    if (seconds !== 0 || millseconds < 1000) {
        timeString += (seconds !== 1) ? (seconds + ' seconds ') : (seconds + ' second ');
    }

    return timeString;
};
});
```

Then use it:

```
<div>{{ millSeconds | millSecondsToTimeString }}</div>
```

Answer (score 11):

There is date converter in AngularJS, just set required date format:

```
{{milliseconds | date:'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm'}}
```

Also I created such 'timeAgo' filter using jQuery timeago() function:

```
.filter('timeAgo', function() {
    return function(input) {
        if (input == null) return "";
        return jQuery.timeago(input);
    };
})
```

Usage:

```
{{milliseconds | timeAgo}}
```

or use together both format for wide date representation:

```
<span>{{milliseconds | timeAgo}}, {{milliseconds  | date:'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm'}}</span>
```

Result:

```
12 minutes ago, 2015-03-04 11:38
```

Answer (score 10):

You'll want to use [moment's](http://momentjs.com/) duration objects.

To do what you want, try this:

```
app.controller 'MainCtrl', ($scope) ->
    $scope.name = 'World'
    $scope.milliseconds = 3600000
    $scope.duration = moment.duration($scope.milliseconds)
```

And the markup

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <p>Milliseconds: {{milliseconds}}</p>
  <p>Duration: {{duration.hours()}}h {{duration.minutes()}}m</p>
</body>
```

plunkr:  http://plnkr.co/edit/2HL75Tmr4CoAy5R9smkx

Answer (score 5):

Thanks. I've modified your filter slightly to return duration in hh:mm:ss format.

```
.filter('duration', function() {
    //Returns duration from milliseconds in hh:mm:ss format.
      return function(millseconds) {
        var seconds = Math.floor(millseconds / 1000);
        var h = 3600;
        var m = 60;
        var hours = Math.floor(seconds/h);
        var minutes = Math.floor( (seconds % h)/m );
        var scnds = Math.floor( (seconds % m) );
        var timeString = '';
        if(scnds < 10) scnds = "0"+scnds;
        if(hours < 10) hours = "0"+hours;
        if(minutes < 10) minutes = "0"+minutes;
        timeString = hours +":"+ minutes +":"+scnds;
        return timeString;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who wants to have comma separators (e.g. '21 days, 14 hours, 7 minutes'):

```
'use strict';

angular.module('contests').filter('duration', function () {
    return function(milliseconds) {
        var seconds = Math.floor(milliseconds / 1000);
        var days = Math.floor(seconds / 86400);
        var hours = Math.floor((seconds % 86400) / 3600);
        var minutes = Math.floor(((seconds % 86400) % 3600) / 60);
        var dateTimeDurationString = '';
        if ((days > 0) && (hours === 0 && minutes === 0)) dateTimeDurationString += (days > 1) ? (days + ' days ') : (days + ' day ');
        if ((days > 0) && (hours > 0 || minutes > 0)) dateTimeDurationString += (days > 1) ? (days + ' days, ') : (days + ' day, ');
        if ((hours > 0) && (minutes > 0)) dateTimeDurationString += (hours > 1) ? (hours + ' hours, ') : (hours + ' hour, ');
        if ((hours > 0) && (minutes === 0)) dateTimeDurationString += (hours > 1) ? (hours + ' hours ') : (hours + ' hour ');
        if (minutes > 0) dateTimeDurationString += (minutes > 1) ? (minutes + ' minutes ') : (minutes + ' minute ');
        return dateTimeDurationString;
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
var app = angular.module ( 'myApp', [] ) ;
app.controller ( 'myController', function ( $scope, $filter) {
    $scope.date = $filter('date')(milliseconds, 'MM/dd/yyyy');
});
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *why* and/or *how* this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('module_name')
        .filter('secondsToDateTime', secondsToDateTime);

    function secondsToDateTime() {
        return function(seconds) {
            return new Date(1970, 0, 1).setSeconds(seconds);
        };
    }
})();


<span>{{seconds | secondsToDateTime | date:'HH:mm:ss'}}</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below syntax

```
$filter('date')(dateObj, format)
```

e.g.

```
$filter('date')(1324339200000, 'dd/MM/yyyy');
```

Answer (score 0):

For TypeScript but could be adapted for any language.

```
convertTimeMS(timeMS: number): string {
  const seconds = Math.floor(timeMS / 1000);
  const minutes = Math.floor(seconds / 60);
  const hours = Math.floor(minutes / 60);

  let str: string = '';

  if(hours > 0) {
    str = str + hours.toString() + 'h ';
  }
  if(minutes%60 > 0) {
    str = str + Number(minutes%60).toString() + 'm ';
  }
  if(seconds%60 > 0) {
    str = str + Number(seconds%60).toString() + 's ';
  }

  return str;
}
```