# Videogular - Date filter in hh:mm:ss format not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, date, datetime, videogular

I am trying to implement Videogular in  my audio player App. Settings in the example code on [this page](http://www.videogular.com/examples/creating-an-audio-player/) are given below:

```
      <vg-time-display>{{ currentTime | date:'mm:ss' }}</vg-time-display>
      <vg-scrub-bar>
        <vg-scrub-bar-current-time></vg-scrub-bar-current-time>
      </vg-scrub-bar>
      <vg-time-display>{{ timeLeft | date:'mm:ss' }}</vg-time-display>
```

However the audios that I am trying to load are more than an hour long, hence I need to implement "hh:mm:ss". When I change the format to `hh:mm:ss` it adds about 5:00 hours to the duration, and 00:01:30 is displayed as 05:01:30

With some adhoc experimentation the following change in "videogular.js" fixes the problem:

```
this.onUpdateTime = function (event) {
  $scope.API.currentTime = 1000 * event.target.currentTime - (1000 * 60 * 300 * 5 * 5);

  if (event.target.duration != Infinity) {
    $scope.API.totalTime = 1000 * event.target.duration - (1000 * 60 * 300 * 5 * 5);
    $scope.API.timeLeft = 1000 * (event.target.duration - event.target.currentTime) - (1000 * 60 * 300 * 5 * 5);
    $scope.API.isLive = false;
  }
}
```

But that also affects the following code which I couldn't fix:

```
  percentTime = 100 * (newCurrentTime / API.totalTime);
  elem.css("width", percentTime + "%");
```

Comment: Sounds like a time zone issue. What time zone are you in? I'm guessing either GMT -5 (Eastern Americas) or GMT +5 (Western Asia).

Comment: That's correct. Its GMT +5.

Comment: So how should I fix it?

Comment: I'm going to have to bow out on this one, I've had nothing but trouble with time zones in JavaScript. But at least we know where the problem likely is.

Comment: hmmmmmm. So What do I do. I am stuck!!! Plus I am not playing with dates. I am merely trying to display Audio's duration.

Comment: @JustinMorgan may be I should abandon Videogular and opt for something else. Any suggestions for Audio Player other than mediaelement that could work on Android and iOS?

Comment: What Videogular version are you using? Those problems should be solved in the latest versions.

Comment: I downloaded during last week (I think 3-4 days back). Have you uploaded any version after that? I was going to scrap the idea of implementing it and looking for alternatives. But if I could get your help, I will definitely give it a try again,

Comment: @elecash kindly check this link and introduce hh: to see the issue: http://codepen.io/2fdevs/pen/tguGx

Comment: @elecash I have also noticed that the Player was visible on emulator but was not visible or working on Android device. Is that a known issue? I want to use it for an Android App.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, that looks more for a lack of feature in AngularJS filter than a problem in Videogular. We're using the AngularJS date filter that as you can see in the AngularJS docs only supports the browser timezone or UTC.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date

If you want to show hours I recommend you to create your own filter to show hours and use that instead of date:'mm:ss'.

As it looks like a good feature for Videogular I will try to take a look to the AngularJS code and add complete timezone support.

Comment: BTW, maybe this is what you're looking for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20196113/angularjs-how-do-you-convert-milliseconds-to-xhours-and-ymins

Comment: Thanks @elecash. I will look at this. However, the other pressing question is if your Videogular would run on Android (old & new) versions. Any advice in this regard?

Comment: Yes, it should work in Android devices, but I usually test on Android 4.3, so I don't know if it would work on legacy Android phones with 2.X or 3.X OS's installed.

Comment: I am using 4.1.2 on Galaxy S2 and its not showing up unfortunately.

Comment: If you figured what happens on Android 4.1.2 it would be great to have a PR on github, thanks

Comment: Thanks @elecash. Unfortunately I have given up and now testing ngAngular to make the audio work. May be later with a later version. Thanks for bearing with me anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to work fine if you specify timezone "+0000" as the second argument to the date filter:

```
<vg-time-display>{{ currentTime | date:'HH:mm:ss':'+0000' }}</vg-time-display>
```