# Convert milliseconds to HH:MM:SS

Tags: angularjs

I have been looking through this code but cant really find any

tried to use angular filtering {{bla.bla | date:'HH:mm:ss'}}

but it doesnt work.
can anybody help me please? thanks!

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20196113/angularjs-how-do-you-convert-milliseconds-to-xhours-and-ymins

Comment: Try this : 
    {{ today | date:'mediumTime' }} <!-- 12:09:02 PM -->
    {{ today | date:'shortTime' }} <!-- 12:09 PM -->

Comment: {{ today | date:'hh:mm:ss.sss' }} this will work as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
filter('songTime',function(){

    return function (s) {
        var ms = s % 1000;
        s = (s - ms) / 1000;
        var secs = s % 60;
        s = (s - secs) / 60;
        var mins = s % 60;
        var hrs = (s - mins) / 60;

        return hrs + ':' + mins + ':' + secs + ':' + ms;        
    };
}
```

and use it like {{bla.bla | songTime }} . You can beautify the date inside the filter.

Comment: the bla bla bla comes from the API sir and it is dynamic, but the value is in milliseconds

Comment: You need to share some code snippet to show your issue. Did u take a look at the plnkr link.

Comment: this is not about today's date sir, basically bla.bla will return a value which is a song playtime, and I need to convert it to HH;MM:SS because it is saved in milliseconds. e.g 170000 miliseconds to 00:02:40 or so

Comment: You will have to write your own filter for that. I have updated the answer

Answer (score 1):

I just came across this question looking for an answer, but couldn't find a good solution, so I made my own filter that does this, if anyone needs it.

```
app.filter('formatDuration', function () {
    return function (input) {
        var totalHours, totalMinutes, totalSeconds, hours, minutes, seconds, result='';

        totalSeconds = input / 1000;
        totalMinutes = totalSeconds / 60;
        totalHours = totalMinutes / 60;

        seconds = Math.floor(totalSeconds) % 60;
        minutes = Math.floor(totalMinutes) % 60;
        hours = Math.floor(totalHours) % 60;

        if (hours !== 0) {
            result += hours+':';

            if (minutes.toString().length == 1) {
                minutes = '0'+minutes;
            }
        }

        result += minutes+':';

        if (seconds.toString().length == 1) {
            seconds = '0'+seconds;
        }

        result += seconds;

        return result;
    };
});
```

Here's an example of it in use:

```
{{247000 | formatDuration}} --> Result: 4:07
{{4748000 | formatDuration}} --> Result: 1:19:08
```

This will work with any amount of hours, minutes, and seconds, and includes leading zeros on numbers when necessary.