# Need to formate number into minutes and seconds counter

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ionic-framework

So essentially I need to format a preset number (300 for example) to display in minutes and seconds (5:00 for example). As the number decreases (it is a countdown...so 299) the display should follow in minutes and seconds rule (4:59).

This is what I have currently have for my formatting (which doesn't work):

```
{{totalTime | date:'ss'}}
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AngularJS - How do you convert milliseconds to xHours and yMins](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20196113/angularjs-how-do-you-convert-milliseconds-to-xhours-and-ymins)

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22962468/angularjs-display-current-date

Comment: This lib will do all you need - http://momentjs.com/

Comment: you could try adding a filter as mentioned in http://stackoverflow.com/a/25779064/3150659